# template meta-programming OR operation

Tags: c++, templates, decorator

I have a class that can be decorated with a set of add-on templates to provide additional functionality. Each add-on has an identifying addon_value that the base class needs to know.

The code below is an example of what I would like to do. Obviously, the main() function fails to compile. The goal is for CBase::GetValueOfAddOns() to know the value of OR-ing  the addon_value for each add-on. The calculation does not actually have to be performed in GetValueOfAddOns(), it just has to be able to get at the result.

```
template< class T >
class AddOn_A : public T
{
public: 
    AddOn_A( int x ) : T( x ) 
    {};

    enum { addon_value = 0x00000001 };
};

template< class T >
class AddOn_B : public T
{
public: 
    AddOn_B( int x ) : T( x ) 
    {};

    enum { addon_value = 0x00000010 };
};

class CBase
{
public:
    explicit CBase( int x ) : x_( x ) 
    {
        // error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall CBase::GetValueOfAddOns(void)const " (?GetValueOfAddOns@CBase@@UBEHXZ)
        int z = GetValueOfAddOns();
    };

    virtual int GetValueOfAddOns() const = 0;

private:
    int x_;
};

// define an empty AddOn
template< class > class empty 
{
public:
    enum { addon_value = 0x00000000 };
};

// forward declaration and Add-On defaults
template< template< class > class AddOn1 = empty,
          template< class > class AddOn2 = empty,
          template< class > class AddOn3 = empty >
class CMyClass;

// specialized template for the default case
template<> class CMyClass< empty, empty, empty > : public CBase
{
public:
    CMyClass( int x ) : CBase( x ) 
    {};

    enum { addon_value = 0x00000000 };
};

// actual definition
template< template< class > class AddOn1,
          template< class > class AddOn2,
          template< class > class AddOn3 >
class CMyClass : public AddOn1< CBase >,
                 public CMyClass< AddOn2, AddOn3 >
{
public:
    CMyClass( int x ) : AddOn1< CBase >( x ),
                        CMyClass< AddOn2, AddOn3 >( x )
    {};

    enum { addon_value = AddOn1< CBase >::addon_value | CMyClass< AddOn2, AddOn3 >::addon_value };

    int GetValueOfAddOns() const
    {
        return addon_value;
    }
};

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    CMyClass< AddOn_A > A( 0 );
    _ASSERT( A.GetValueOfAddOns() == AddOn_A< CBase >::addon_value );

    CMyClass< AddOn_A, AddOn_B > AB( 0 );
    _ASSERT( AB.GetValueOfAddOns() == ( AddOn_A< CBase >::addon_value | AddOn_B< CBase >::addon_value ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help,
PaulH

Comment: You can't call virtual methods from the constructor or destructor. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Martin York - So, is there any way to get the addon_value in the CBase ctor() or is that unreasonable?

Comment: Martin York: Calling virtual functions is fine, unless they are pure. The only bit that confuses people is that they will only point to the most derived object that's been constructed - which almost always means the call is effectively not virtual. Likewise for destructors - the most derived object that hasn't finished its destructor is called.

Comment: @martin: Your comment makes we wish we could down-vote comments. It is certainly not undefined behavior - unless the function is pure virtual.

Comment: @coppro and @sbi: while I agree it's not undefined behavior... the fact that it only call the virtual override of the moment (which might be undefined...) makes it quite difficult to use... and I would certainly gives the same councel as Martin's to any beginner!

Comment: @PaulH: while I appreciate the fact that you are in trouble, this is basically the 3rd question about the same hierarchy of class... and you got it as wrong as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608733/ambiguous-access-when-calling-a-decorated-base-class, it would be nice if you could group questions... you're going straight in a wall there!

Comment: @Matthieu: The advice might be sound, but it has to be based on correct facts. (It might even be that Martin had just forgotten to stick a "virtual" into his question somewhere. But it _is_ wrong without that and that needed to be pointed out lest it's archived wrong for all eternity.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the most elegant way, but the following is fairly straightforward:

Add this to CMyClass:

```
enum {AddonsValues = AddOn1<CBase>::addon_value | CMyClass<AddOn2, AddOn3>::AddonsValues};

int GetValueOfAddOns()
{
    // return the result of OR-ing the addon_value of each add-on.
    return AddonsValues;
};
```

and this to the specialized `CMyClass<empty, empty, empty>`:

```
enum {AddonsValues = 0};
```

Comment: I dunno. It's no less elegant than the rest of the code at least. I like it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make that function pure `virtual`, you can implement it in `CMyClass`, where you have all information available. Just change your `empty` class to define `enum { addon_value = 0x00000000 };`, which will make this easier.

Comment: That + Eric's comment above work great, except CBase() still can't "know" the value. I've modified the code in the original post to show the linker error. I get when I try to access GetValueOfAddons() from the CBase::ctor. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to call that function from the ctor of `CBase`? Virtual functions don't work the way most people expect them to from ctors and dtors. If it's just the ctor, you could just pass the value as an argument to it. Otherwise, the virtual function will work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it better:

See your new question about [the problem with hierarchy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608733/ambiguous-access-when-calling-a-decorated-base-class) I have solved the AddOnValues problem there as well, and there is no need for template meta-programming, really.